# Init function runs multiple times

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my javascript code. I have an init function that calls a function, getDevices() and then writes a console message. the getDevices function has a 4D array, that is used as a parameter to a new function called objectify. This function will create an object of the 4D array data. But my problem is that when i do a push to a another array where the new objects will be stored the init function runs again.

```
vm = this;
vm.dataObj = [];

(function init(){
    getData();
    console.debug("im in init!");
 })();

function getData(){
    var data = [
      [1, 2, 3, 4],
      [1, 2, 3, 4],
      [1, 2, 3, 4],
      [1, 2, 3, 4]
    ];
    objectify(data);
}



 function objectify(dataArray){
        vm.dataObj = [];
        for(var i=0; i < dataArray.length; i++ ){
            vm.dataObj .push({
                nr1: dataArray[i][0],
                nr2: dataArray[i][1],
                nr3: dataArray[i][2],
                nr4: dataArray[i][3]
            });
        }
    }
```

From the code above the console message "im in init" is run 5 times, but when i remove the push the console message is only written once. How is this possible?

Comment: [Seems to only run once, here](https://jsfiddle.net/btth162t/).

Comment: Are you sure the only reason to repeat is the `push` ?

Comment: `init` is a IIFE. It will be called only once. Even explicit calls will not be allowed. If its being called multiple times, check if file is loaded multiple time.

Comment: run one time for me...

Comment: it seems that the vm you are running this code in is loading the script multiple times

Comment: I tried to change the vm.device to var device in the objectify function, and now it works as it should. So i guess the push is not my problem, vm.devices is the problem.

Comment: nope, not using ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what caused my problem. I was searching on the wrong places as some of the comments suggested. The error happend because i was using ui-grid with angular, in one of the columnDefs of the grid config i used a cellTemplate. That looked like this:

```
'<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ngCellText" ng-controller="DevicesController as vm"><a ng-click="vm.goToDevice(row.entity)">{{COL_FIELD}}</a></div>',
```

Meaning the ng-controller was the cause of the multiple init.

Comment: Did you find any nice way to continue to use this code without calling the init function multiple times?